# Flex : Menu doesn't hide automatically?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I am creating a menu this way :

```
myMenu = Menu.createMenu( null, myMenuXMLListCollection, false );
```

and then showing it with :

```
myMenu.popup( 10, 10 );
```

but the menu doesn't disappear automatically when i click somewhere outside the menu.

- Is there some way to make the menu disappear automatically when i click outside it ?

Comment: You could add a listener to the stage click and if the click's x,y isn't within the menu, hide it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen for the [SandBoxMouseEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/SandboxMouseEvent.htm).[MOUSE_UP_SOMEWHERE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/SandboxMouseEvent.html#MOUSE_UP_SOMEWHERE) on the sandbox root.  You can get the Sandbox root using [SystemManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/SystemManager.html).[getSandboxRoot](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/SystemManager.html#getSandboxRoot%28%29)

So, add your event listener, something like this:

```
systemManager.getSandBoxRoot.addEventListener(SandboxMouseEvent.MOUSE_UP_SOMEWHERE, myMouseUpHandler);
```

And then in your event handler, just check to see if the target is the menu and if not hide the menu:

```
protected function myMouseUpHandler(event:SandboxMouseEvent):void{
  if(event.target != myMenuInstance){
    myMenuInstance.visible = false;
    // or whatever other action you wish to take to hide the menu.
  }
}
```

This is the general approach that the Flex ComboBox uses to hide the drop down menu on mouse click.

Comment: thank You very very much Flextras.com :) ( lifesaver again ) :)